# issues in indexing a class in Java

Tags: java

I have happened to have a problem in defining an array where the index should be elements of a class as follows:

MWE:

```
package thisModel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThisCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Arc {
            private int i; //starting node
            private int j; // ending node

            public Arc(int i, int j) {
                this.i = i;
                this.j = j;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j);
            }
        } 

        List<Arc> arcs = new ArrayList<Arc>();

            int N = 7;
            int [] b = new int [N];


    }

}
```

so, here, if I define the array as follows:

```
int [] y = new int [arcs.size()];
```

Then, errors are popping up in the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

                    //my issue lies here: 
                    //y[Arc(i,j)] - y[Arc(j,i)] = b[i];
                }
            }
```

and I think it is because `y[arcs.size()]` has a dimension of the size of the list, but not its elements.

My question is if there is any way to define the `y` like as an array of `Arc` not `arcs.size()` like this:

```
int[] y = new int [Arc(i,j)];
```

Comment: What would be the dimension if you defined it off of the `Arc` object? Are you trying to define it off of the `Arc`'s `i` or `j` variable?

Comment: @GBlodgett Actually, the dimension is the number the Arc elements in arcs list, and it is know as an input. for instance, it is 15.

Comment: And because `Arc` is not `final`, what should happen if I do `class Bad extends Arc {private Arc newDimension; ...}`.

Comment: If you did define `y` as `int[] y = new int [Arc(i,j)];` what would be the length of `y`?

Comment: Did you try  `System.out.println(arcs.size());` to see what you are getting ?

Comment: Also in the line `y[Arc(i,j)] - y[Arc(j,i)] = b[i];` (Aside from tying to pass `Arc(i, j)` as an index of `y`) the left hand side must be a variable

Comment: @GBlodgett well, the size of y, if I define it as int[] y = new int [Arc(i,j)]; should be arcs.size(); and it is known beforehand. And, yes, the left hand side of the equation will be a variable which I will be using ilog.concert.IloNumVar to define it. My problem is that how to index elements like y[Arc(i,j)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `y` as a two-dimensional array

```
int[][] y = new int[N][N];
```

then you can use the `Arc`'s components `i` and `j` as index of `y` to retrieve values:

```
int value = y[i][j];
```

You can also type it as a `Map` (if I read your first sentence literally):

```
Map<Arc, Integer> y = new HashMap<>();
```

This allows you to get values from `y` by asking for them with a particular `Arc` instance:

```
Arc myArc = ...;
int value = y.get(myArc);
```

In this case you should define proper `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `Arc` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object x) {
  if (!(x instanceof Arc)) return false;
  Arc that = (Arc) x;
  return this.i == that.i && this.j == that.j;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.i + 31*this.j;
}
```

otherwise the `HashMap` will not find any values if you try to get them by passing new `Arc` instances with same components to it.

Comment: could you also add the way you may define the equation:
y[Arc(i,j)] - y[Arc(j,i)] = b[i];

Comment: Sure. I assume you really mean *equation* and not *assignment*. It should be either `y[i][j] - y[j][i] == b[i]` or `y.get(new Arc(i,j)) - y.get(new Arc(j,i)) == b[i]` (depends on which data structure you have chosen). If you are using the latter, make sure that for each pair `(i, j)` you have created an `Arc` and assigned a value to it in the `Map` beforehand. Maybe staying with arrays is the better choice.